# Fail to set selected in combobox jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

i'm loading a combo-box dynamically with jquery, after renderized, this combo have the follow structure

```
<select id="cboCliente" class="form-control">
     <option value="0">Selecione...</option>
     <option value="1">Cliente 0</option>
     <option value="2">Cliente 1</option>
     <option value="3">Cliente 2</option>
</select>
```

After some validation, i try to set one of this options as "selected", but don't work. This is my code:

```
$('#cboCliente option[value='+ m.getIdCliente() +']').prop('selected', true);
```

the method `getIdCliente()` is working fine, i receive the value "1".

The thing is, the jQuery can't set the selected option, and when a try for the Developer tools of chrome, everything works fine.

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: What is m in m.getIdCliente()?  [in this fiddle works](http://jsfiddle.net/9LYdC/)

Comment: I know what i'm doing wrong, i'm loading the combo-box asynchronous, when i change to synchronous everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$("#cboCliente").val(m.getIdCliente());
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GNzSL/

Answer (score 0):

can we cache it first like this?

```
var selected = '#cboCliente option[value='+ m.getIdCliente() +']';
    $(selected).prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.